# Static linking against Qt on Windows using CMake

Tags: windows, qt, cmake, qt5, qmake

I'm working on a Qt project that is developed on Linux, but also has a statically linked Windows build. I can build it on Linux and Windows using the same CMakeLists.txt file. It strips down to:

```
project(muckturnier)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_REQUIRED TRUE)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Sql)
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDES} ${Qt5Sql_INCLUDES})
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(muckturnier_SRCS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SomeCode.cpp)
add_executable(muckturnier ${muckturnier_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(muckturnier ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES} ${Qt5Sql_LIBRARIES})
```

But I didn't manage to do a statically linked build on Windows via CMake yet. When I manually set the respective include dirs, all builds fine, but I get a linker error in the end:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable muckturnier.exe
C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o):qtextengine.cpp:(.text+0x228d):
undefined reference to `hb_buffer_create'
C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o):qtextengine.cpp:(.text+0x22a4):
undefined reference to `hb_buffer_set_unicode_funcs'
C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o):qtextengine.cpp:(.text+0x22b7):
undefined reference to `hb_buffer_pre_allocate'
C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o):qtextengine.cpp:(.text+0x22bf):
undefined reference to `hb_buffer_allocation_successful'
C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o):qtextengine.cpp:(.text+0x23ef):
undefined reference to `hb_buffer_clear_contents'
C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o):qtextengine.cpp:(.text+0x241f):
undefined reference to `hb_buffer_add_utf16'
C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o):qtextengine.cpp:(.text+0x2432):
undefined reference to `hb_buffer_set_segment_properties'
C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o):qtextengine.cpp:(.text+0x243a):
undefined reference to `hb_buffer_guess_segment_properties'
C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o):qtextengine.cpp:(.text+0x2455):
undefined reference to `hb_buffer_set_flags'
C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o):qtextengine.cpp:(.text+0x2555):
undefined reference to `hb_shape_full'
C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o):qtextengine.cpp:(.text+0x2578):
undefined reference to `hb_buffer_get_length'
C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o):qtextengine.cpp:(.text+0x258c):
undefined reference to `hb_buffer_destroy'
C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o):qtextengine.cpp:(.text+0x264a):
undefined reference to `hb_buffer_get_glyph_infos'
C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o):qtextengine.cpp:(.text+0x2662):
undefined reference to `hb_buffer_get_glyph_positions'
C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o):qtextengine.cpp:(.text+0x28f8):
undefined reference to `hb_buffer_reverse'
C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o):qtextengine.cpp:(.text+0x2941):
undefined reference to `hb_buffer_destroy'
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w
64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Qt/5.6_static/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qtextengine.o): bad relo
c address 0x7a in section `.text$_ZN7QVectorIN11QTextLayout11FormatRangeEEaSERKS
2_[__ZN7QVectorIN11QTextLayout11FormatRangeEEaSERKS2_]'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\muckturnier.dir\build.make:424: recipe for target 'muckturnier.exe' f
ailed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [muckturnier.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:141: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/muckturnier.dir/all' fai
led
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/muckturnier.dir/all] Error 2
makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is why I created a qmake .pro file to do the static build. This one strips down to:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
CONFIG += qt
CONFIG += static
QT += widgets
QT += sql
HEADERS += SomeCode.h
SOURCES += SomeCode.cpp
TARGET = muckturnier
```

Using qmake (from the static Qt), I can do the static build without a problem. So my static Qt build is just fine, and it's a CMake problem.

What's wrong here? Thanks for all help!

Comment: Try using Qt5_INCLUDES and Qt5_LIBRARIES instead of specific module includes and libraries. Also, when building with qmake look at commands executed and note list of Qt libraries linked. It may give you some clues.

Comment: What's happen in case you use `qt5_use_modules(muckturnier Widgets Sql)`  instead of `target_link_libraries(...)`?

Comment: According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html , this macro should only be used with older cmake versions if I read this correctly? I used the current stable one. I Fear peppe below is right and it's a bug … I'll check this anway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're a victim of [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38913) (still unsolved). I'm not 100% sure of what's going wrong, but you can find some ideas in the comments.

Comment: This bug actually looks a lot like what I get … it's not exactly the same, but probably, you're right!